# Availability Message Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-view, stock-status

I am currently having an issue with the position of the availability message that appears on the product page. The message swaps from the desired position "In Stock" across from the Price, to before the price when out of stock.

Image1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AxSp.png
  Image 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EoeS.png

Here is the code used for the current situation:

```
<div <?php if ($useRichSnippets) echo $helperSnippets->getOfferItemscope(); ?>>
            <div class="product-type-data<?php echo $productTypeClasses; ?>"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data'); ?></div>              
            <?php echo $priceProperties; ?>
        </div> <?php //end: offers ?>

        <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml(); ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a CSS issue. Check the class(es) of the DIV when "out of stock". Looks like the CSS for "in stock" is `float: right` and "out of stock" has `float: left`.